# Non-JavaFX thread communication with JavaFX thread

Tags: java, javafx, java-threads

I am making a socket which is listening for inputs (currently just from the Terminal). When I read the input, I want to call a function in a controller class which then sends it to my application GUI. It should be an easy task, but there seems to be something I have to do in order for my socket thread to communicate with the JavaFX threads.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
```

is the exception I get. Is there any easy workaround for this problem I am having?

Relevant code:

```
//Socket Class

/**
*Initiates the socket
*/
public void run() {
    this.startSocket();                                                  *5
}


/**
* Listens for user input
*/
private void startSocket() {
    String input;
    while(true) {
        input=scanner.next();
        handle(input);                                                   *4
    }
}

/**
* Handles user input
*/
private void handle(String s) {
    String[] a = s.split(",");
    int[] ab = {Integer.parseInt(a[0]), 
          Integer.parseInt(a[1]),Integer.parseInt(a[2])};

    clientController.changeLightSequence(ab[0], ab[1], ab[2]);           *3
}
```

```
//Controller Class
/**
*Sends a command to GUI
*/
public void changeLightSequence(int red, int yellow, int green) {
    clientGUI.changeLightSequence(red, yellow, green);                   *2
}
```

```
//GUI class
/**
* Handles user input-command.
*/
public void changeLightSequence(int red, int yellow, int green) {
    //setRunningTimeLine(red, yellow, green);
    hostField.setText("Hello world!");                                   *1
    animation();
}
```

Stack Trace with my relevant code:

```
at Client.ClientGUI.changeLightSequence(ClientGUI.java:225)              *1
at Client.ClientController.changeLightSequence(ClientController.java:26) *2
at Client.ClientSocket.handle(ClientSocket.java:120)                     *3
at Client.ClientSocket.startSocket(ClientSocket.java:83)                 *4
at Client.ClientSocket.run(ClientSocket.java:88)                         *5
```

Comment: Would you please remove this duplicate tag. My app does not hang. That is a completly different scenario I've already taken care of. The problem I am having is that I can't communicate between the threads themselves.

Comment: You didn't read that question and answer then. Also, please consider [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+Not+on+FX+Application+Thread) before posting a question.

Comment: I did. I saw the post before you decided to check in, and that post really does not answer my question. I might just not see the similarity, but you can't just assume every iteration of a problem is solved by answering one of them.

Comment: To paraphrase that question "My app throws a IllegalArgumentException: Not on FX Application Thread when I am running code from a background thread. When I tried to fix it, the application hangs." The answer shows the correct fix. If you don't understand it, try one of the other 286 duplicates that come up in the search.

Comment: Spare your sarcasm. You should take in to consideration that people use this forum because they actually require help. If that post you are linking was actually helpfull to me, we would not be having this conversation. Or any other related post for that matter

Comment: None of that was sarcastic. There are 286 hits on the search I linked; all of them are asking the same thing. All of those with answers - including the one I directly linked - answer your question with "wrap the code that changes the UI in `Platform.runLater(...)`. Perhaps you should consider the idea that being pointed to something you can read that has the answer to your question is more helpful to you in the long run than spoonfeeding you code.

Comment: This is going anywhere. If you think I asked this question without trying and researching it first, so be it.

Comment: @Adrian Why don't you just do what James_D has suggested. Wrap up your last piece of code from above in a Platform.runLater() call. The answer to your question would not get any better if it is answered individually the 287th time.

Comment: I have tried that. I even did before the link was suggested. I have tried to multiple ways to solve this, but neither have worked so far. This reason is why I posted the question with all the relevant code. I can understand that all of this looks simple for all seasoned programmers. Would it help if I littered the post with how I have tried to solve this? I am working on trying to understand Platform.runLater() better, as he suggested that as a solution (which yes, I did think could not solve my problem, as I tried it earlier without success).

Comment: James_D is a very experienced JavaFX developer. He's correct when he says that you just need to wrap any call you want to happen on the JavaFX Application Thread in a call to `Platform.runLater()`. That static method takes in an instance of `Runnable`, and will execute that `Runnable` on the JavaFX Application Thread. If you're developing against Java 8 or later, you can use a lambda to make things more concise if you like: `Platform.runLater(() -> clientController.changeLightSequence(ab[0], ab[1], ab[2]));`

Comment: @Adrian In that case, you are asking the wrong question. The answer to the question you have posted is - as is stated many times on this forum - use `Platform.runLater()`. If that hasn't worked for you, then either you have used it incorrectly (which tbh seems unlikely, given how well-organized your existing code is), or you have other errors in your code: you need to ask a question that addresses that issue rather than the one you have asked. There is no possible answer to the question you have actually asked that is any different to the existing answers.

Comment: The other option you have is to wrap code you need to run in a background thread in a `Task<V>` object, and send that to an `ExecutorService.submit()` call. The success/failure handlers on the Task instance handle the thread switching for you, which is kinda nice.

Comment: @Cypher `Task`s are better suited for one-off operations; the example here has a never-ending runnable. (Yes, you can make it work, but really a thread here is a better solution than encapsulating the work to be done in a task.)

Comment: @James_D That's true. My last comment wasn't very well thought out. He's obviously handling threads already anyway. :)  Adrian what happens when you try the call to Platform.runLater()? You said you've tried it already, but it didn't solve your problem. What exactly happened?

Comment: I was not aware of what I should use. Like I stated earlier, I tried different ways of solving it, but I could not make them work. Thankfully, Platform.runLater(() -> clientController.changeLightSequence(ab[0], ab[1], ab[2]));worked perfectly. I didn't realize it had to be on the thread that is not a JavaFX-thread. Thank you for your time and help :)